# wxPython wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl case insensitive highlighting

Tags: wxpython, scintilla, forth

I'm using the `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl` in and application where I am using  it to highlight Forth:

```python
self.styled_text_ctrl = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetLexer(wx.stc.STC_LEX_FORTH)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetMarginType(0, wx.stc.STC_MARGIN_NUMBER)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetMarginWidth(1, 0)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetMarginWidth(2, 0)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetWrapMode(wx.stc.STC_WRAP_WORD)
self.styled_text_ctrl.SetKeyWords(2,": VARIABLE CREATE VALUE CONSTANT USER USER-CREATE VOCABULARY TASK")
```

The problem I am having is that it will only recognize the keyword if it is in the case it was given in, a problem as the Forth I am using is case insensitive. Other than putting in every upper and lowercase combination of a word into the key words is there a way to turn off the case sensitivity on the keywords?